# How to filter dataframe based on values in pyspark/python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I have a dataframe like below. I want to read the dataframe and filter the records based on start time and store in different dataframes.

INPUT DF

```
name      start_time
AA        2022-11-16
AAA       2022-11-15
BBB       2022-11-14
```

For eg:
I need to store each record based on start time, which means all, 16 th date start time records should go to one dataframe and so on.

OUTPUT DF

```
df1 = ["Store 2022-11-16 record"]
df2 = ["Store 2022-11-15 record"]
df3 = ["Store 2022-11-14 record"]
```

Comment: what do you mean by "Store 2022-11-16 record" ? does it contain the rest of the data coresponding to that one start_time

Comment: this might help also : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46476310/python-looping-and-creating-new-dataframe-for-each-value-of-a-column

Comment: @grymlin I have a csv file with different date start time values records. I need to store each record based on start time, which means all 16 th date start time records should go to one dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Well, technially a duplicate but idk how to report that but I think this works :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"name" : ["AA", "AAA", "BBB"], 
"start_time" : ["2022-11-16"," 2022-11-15", "2022-11-14"]})

dfs = dict(tuple(df.groupby('start_time')))

dfs
```

you can select each DataFrame by the start time :

```
print (dfs['2022-11-14''])

    name    start_time
2   BBB 2022-11-14
```

Comment: Thanks @grymlin But date should be passed dynamically, no hardcoding.

Comment: what do you mean? the one line creates all the dataframe dynamically

Comment: Yes, but we are selecting dataframe by hardcoding the date. Rather, it should have dataframe for each starttime and we should get it by printing the dataframe

Comment: can you give an example please? here each dataframe is inside a dic, would you like to store it in a different structure?

Comment: I would like to store each record having one particular start time  in one dataframe. In the same way, I need to store above mentioned three records in three differenct dataframe. Since all three have different start time